# How to CREATE multiple TYPEs in one LOOP in pl/pgsql?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I want to create many TYPEs that are similar to each other, which might have different length, e.g.

```
CREATE TYPE TP_A (
    internallength = 8,
    input = tp_a_in,
    output = tp_a_out,
    storage = plain,
    alignment = double
};
```

the format of input and output functions are the same, and i want to loop the the name of the type ("tp_a") and internallength (8) in my arrays, e.g. `names={tp_a,tp_b,tp_c,tp_d}; lens={8,8,16,32}`.

How could i do this? Could i just declare the names into a text[] and loop on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to adapt following code to the CREATE TYPE statements you are using:

```
do
$$
declare
 tn text[] = '{"tp_a", "tp_b"}';
 tl int[] = '{8, 16}';
begin
 for i in 1..2
 loop
 execute format('create type %I as (field%s int)', tn[i] , tl[i]);
 end loop;
end;
$$;
```

See [FORMAT function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT).

Comment: seems that it could not link the string and find the function. For the line `input=tp_a_in` I can't get it with `input=%I_in`